# Recording the number of responses in my Job Portal for an Ongoing Job

Tags: google-analytics

I have got an web app which is a like a Job Portal. I want to record the number of applications received so far for particular job opening in the google analytics. How can I do so??

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm thinking of passing an utm whenever anyone applies for a particular job and recording that url will be counted as my conversion. Will this approach be fine?